# Should I accept Ubuntu updates if I'm running 10.04 netbook remix or move to Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-netbook

I am a novice Linux/Ubuntu user. I finally gave up on my HP Mini Mie and took a shot at loading Ubuntu before throwing it away. Well, I found a copy of 10.04 (netbook remix), downloaded it and actually love it compared to what I had before. However, I'm getting recommended updates and I've accepted some of them without any problem. I'm concerned that eventually 10.04 might not work well with some of the updates. Should I be happy with what I have and not accept updates or should I move on to something more current that will run on my Atom processor? I would like to continue using Firefox, OpenOffice and Reader but that's about it. Would Lubuntu be a smart option?

Thanks,

Comment: While it's generally recommended to install updates, be advices that 10.04 is no longer supported. In case you decide to go with Lubuntu, try 13.04. It's a tough choice, as the NBR was made with netbooks in mind, while Lubuntu not so much.

Comment: Are you suggesting ubuntu 13.04 or lubuntu 13.04? I'vd downloaded a usb live stick with lubuntu 12.04 and thought I would give it a try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you should move to Lubuntu. The reason of it is that it's much lighter than Ubuntu and will make your system performance much better. Be sure to make a clean install (it's recommended) and after it you can install OpenOffice, Firefox, etc...